# Installation problems on USB , partition table

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb

Although I have built computers in the past, I know next to nothing about Ubuntu or Linux.

I decided to try to use Ubuntu on a 16GB f;ash drive as a substitute hard drive and it works fine on the "Try without installing" lest for not having flash among other things , but whenever I do try to install I get a problem.

On "Installation Type" I have `/dev/sda` and new partition table is grayed out, on clicking the + Ubuntu crashes and on clicking continue I get `no root system filed is defined`. I've been doing research, but none of the answers I find seem relevant. I was wondering if I could get help from some of the experts?

[image]

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Newer UEFI system or old BIOS/MBR system? Do you have Windows hibernated/fast start up on? or RAID configuration. Those often prevent Linux drivers from correctly seeing drive. Post this: `sudo parted -l` from terminal in live installer.

Comment: Its a samsung laptop , and a pretty old one at that (old as far as laptop go I suppose). It does have an AMD graphics card (7800M) although I do not need it for all its worth. There is no RAID on it. Probably not a valid question here anymore , but I did manage to get Installation type working (as everyone else) on Linux Mint.

Comment: This problem usually indicates a lack of drivers for the disk controller circuits on the computer. Using a newer version of Ubuntu may help (try 16.10, or even the 17.04 beta that was recently released). You may also be able to get it to show up by tweaking firmware settings related to AHCI.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is select the mount point for "/".

Comment: I tried using that but it doesn't give me any options other than /dev/sda. Clicking on it just momentarily turns it orange , doesn't allow me to do anything there.

Comment: Try to take a picture of your screen (not screenshot), post it online and paste the link here. You can use imgur, it is very easy and doesn't require an account. If you need to, take a series of pictures for the whole problem.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/0cD1u  , here you go , I had to split it between to pictures

Comment: Have you tried going into the "change" menu?

Comment: I did , but nothing happened. Same with - , and + gave me a crash.

Comment: Go into live session, and open up gparted (you can do Ctrl+Alt+T to open up a terminal and type in "gparted"). With this you can create a partition which will help your issue. Go [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/) to see how to make a partition.